# Función VBA en acces que devuleve una matriz

Tags: vba, ms-access

Quiero que una función me devuelva una matriz pero me sale un error de compilación: 'No se puede asignar a una matriz'
El código es este:

```
Private Function función1()
Dim resultado(1) As Integer
resultado = función2(1,1) 'Se produce el error: no se puede asignar a una matriz'
End Function

Private Function función2(Referencia, Cantidad) As Integer()
Dim resultado(1) As Integer
resultado(0) = referencia * 2
resultado(1) = cantidad * 4
función2 = resultado
End Function
```

Estoy utilizando access 2007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero, si defines tu variable en un módulo fuera de todo procedimiento o función, justo debajo de `Option Explicit`, tendrás la variable definida en todos tus procedimientos, y no tienes que estar definiéndola todo el rato. Prueba con esto: Inserta un módulo estandar, borra todo y copia y pega.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim Resultado(1) As Integer

Sub Actualizar_Resultado(ByVal Referencia As Integer, ByVal Cantidad As Integer)
Resultado(0) = Referencia * 2
Resultado(1) = Cantidad * 4
End Sub
```

Ahora, cada vez que ejecutes el sub `Actualizar_Resultado`, tu matriz Resultado se actualizará según los números que hayas introducido en Referencia y en Cantidad.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba:
Quitando los paréntesis finales al tipo devuelto por la función. Agrega el tipo a los argumentos.

```
Private Function función2(Referencia As Integer, Cantidad As Integer) As Integer
        Dim resultado(1) As Integer
        resultado(0) = Referencia * 2
        resultado(1) = Cantidad * 4
        función2 = resultado
End Function
```